# PDO query returns 0 when it should return rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using PHP PDO to run queries. I have the following function:

```
protected function isStoreRegistered($name, $street1 ,$city, $country_id, $id) {

if($id == '0') {
  $sql = " SELECT a.name, b.street1, b.city, c.id
           FROM tablea a
           LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fk_addressID = b.id
           LEFT JOIN tablec c ON b.fk_countryID = c.id
           WHERE a.name = '$name'
           AND b.street1 = '$street1'
           AND b.city = '$city'
           AND b.fk_countryID = '$country_id'";
  $result = $this->db->exec($sql);
} else {
  // some other query
}

return $result;
```

}

The query sent to MySQL looks like this:

```
 SELECT a.name, b.street1, b.city, c.id
 FROM sl_store a
 LEFT JOIN sl_address b ON a.fk_addressID = b.id
 LEFT JOIN sl_country c ON b.fk_countryID = c.id
 WHERE a.name = 'test store'
 AND b.street1 = 'Weselsgate 2'
 AND b.city = 'Oslo'
 AND b.fk_countryID = 'NO'
```

Runnign this query in Toad, returns 1 row.

But if I do a `print_r(result)`, it outputs `0` (zero)

How can I find out what is wrong here?

Comment: If you are going to downvote, at least write why. Yes I know it states clearly in the manual that it will not work for `SELECT` statements, but that was something I forgot in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php):

> PDO::exec() does not return results from a SELECT statement.

And since youre not modifying anything (no insert, delete, or update) there are no rows affected, which is what `PDO::exec` does return.

If you want the data use a prepared statement or `PDO::query`. If you want the number of rows the use a count in your select.

Comment: Ah shit, you're right. I thought the PDO::exec() was for general queries. Looing at other code, I'm just using for specdial inserts, deletions and updates.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously and in the manual, `PDO::exec()` does not return results from a `SELECT` statement. Instead you should try the following (note the parameter binding):

```
protected function isStoreRegistered($name, $street1 ,$city, $country_id, $id) {

if ($id == '0') {
  $sql = " SELECT a.name, b.street1, b.city, c.id
           FROM tablea a
           LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.fk_addressID = b.id
           LEFT JOIN tablec c ON b.fk_countryID = c.id
           WHERE a.name = :name
           AND b.street1 = :street
           AND b.city = :city
           AND b.fk_countryID = :country";
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare( $sql );
  $vars = array(
    'name'      => $name,
    'street'    => $street1,
    'city'      => $city,
    'country'   => $country_id,
  );
  $result = $stmt->execute( $vars );
} else {
  // some other query
}

return $result;
```

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit quick using `PDO:exec`. I've been using it multiple times, but not for normal SELECT. I ended up using the method you suggested here - it's what I've done in other palces in the code as well. Soemtimes one forgets in the heat of the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

`exec` is returning the number of rows affected by the statement,
in your case, is zero because you are doing a select

docs:- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

your sql is not using PDO in proper manner,
is vulnerable for SQL injection,
spent some reading on the [parameters binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)