# How to select data from database using php_pdo_oci?

Tags: php, oracle

I am using php_pdo_oci to select a query on my oracle database. The problem is it returns a empty value even though there is a value to be return.

**PHP Version: 5.4.31**
**Database: Oracle 9i**

Here is my connection, I tried using **PDO::FETCH_BOTH**, **PDO::FETCH_ASSOC**, **PDO::FETCH_NUM** still no luck. it still returns 0. Take note that the connection returns ok.

```
 public function databaseConnection(){
    # if connection already exists
    if ($this->db_connection != null) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        try {
            $this->db_connection = new PDO('oci:dbname='. DB_NAME . ';', DB_USER, DB_PASS,  array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();    
        }
    }
    # default return
    return false;
}
```

Here is the function I use to check the user if exist:

```
public function check_user_exist($username, $active){
    $sql = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT USERNAME FROM ASUSERACCOUNT WHERE USERNAME = :username AND ACTIVE = :active');
    $sql->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $sql->bindParam(':active', $active);

    if($sql->execute()){
        return $sql->rowCount();
    }
    else{
        return $sql->errorInfo();
    }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What `error` you receive? did you check your `error.log` for a possible main `PHP` errors?

Comment: @BurhanKashour thats the thing there is no error

Comment: Try to activate the `error_reporting` , [more information](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @BurhanKashour I added it still no error

Comment: Okay then instead of return try to `print_r` the result

Comment: @BurhanKashour tried it still no error I am just getting 0

Comment: getting 0 means there is not data in the database, are you sure you check the right data? How do you get the `username` ?

Comment: @BurhanKashour I am sure that there is a data on my database the problem is even if I use `SELECT * FROM ASUSERACCOUNT` I still get 0 result

Comment: I've posted an answer, you need to use a count in your select query

Answer (score 0):

According to @prodigitalson [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8435789/6117399)

From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php):

> PDO::exec() does not return results from a SELECT statement.

And since youre not modifying anything (no insert, delete, or update) there are no rows affected, which is what `PDO::exec` does return.

If you want the data use a prepared statement or `PDO::query`. If you want the number of rows the use a count in your select.

Comment: I tried to use `SELECT COUNT(USERNAME) AS TOTAL FROM ASUSERACCOUNT WHERE USERNAME = :username` still I am getting 0 result